# using ngrok with websocket (or socket.io)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, ngrok

Are there any simple sample code showing ngrok forwarding socket.io/websocket (running under nodejs on localhost)?

In other words, does

```
ngrok http 3000
```

work with a nodejs server and socket.io running on port 3000? Or something like

```
ngrok http+tcp 3000 (just wild guessing)
```

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer and accept it, it will be clearer

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  If your node app is working off of port 3000 like in your example then just use ngrok to create a reverse proxy to expose 3000 to the world.  Websockets will work just fine with it.

Answer (score 4):

(*Self-answer moved from the question into the answers section*)

simply use

```
ngrok http 3000
```

You will see the web address string that localhost binds to. So in the client javascript code, change

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://94349fe6.ngrok.io');
```

NOTE:

`http://94349fe6.ngrok.io` is just that web address string. Yours will be different from this one.

Actually, if one simply does:

```
var socket = io();
```

as the [introduction to socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) states:

> it defaults to trying to connect to the host that serves the page

So it works as well.

Comment: I'm trying to establish connection through JavaScript's WebSocket constructor and it says that the protocol needs to be `ws://` or `wss://`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **use the socket on ngrok** then you just need to create the ngork link using

```
ngrok tcp 3000

//and hit you Socket API endpoint like: 
tcp.ngrok.io:15819/api/v1/partner/profile?partner_id=27
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using LocalTunnel:

```
Usage: lt --port [num] <options>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel